# Add organisational unit (ou) to organisation (o) in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

On a Debian Buster installation I have just installed the OpenLDAP server `slapd` with:

```
~$ sudo apt install slapd ldap-utils
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

On its setup with default options I was prompted to give an organisation name. I used *home*, so I get

```
~$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -b dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
dn: dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: home
dc: hoeft-online

dn: cn=admin,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
```

Now I try to add an organisational unit (**ou**) to the organisation `o: home` as shown in the output but without success:

```
~$ cat add.ldif
dn: ou=posix,o=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: posix

~$ ldapadd -xWD cn=admin,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de -f add.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=posix,o=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
        matched DN: dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
```

Adding an **ou** to the domainComponent (**dc**) works:

```
~$ cat add.ldif
dn: ou=posix,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: posix

~$ ldapadd -xWD cn=admin,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de -f add.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=posix,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de"
```

What I'm missing here? Isn't it possible to add an organizationalUnit (**ou**) to an organisation (**o**)? If not, why? Where is it defined?

Comment: Long time since I last used slapd. Still do you have an ou on the o on the schemas?

Comment: @vfbsilva No, there is nothing else on the ldap server. It's a virgin installation from the default setup. I have updated the question.

Comment: I would have thought O was a terminal node (like DN). Looking at my configuration (AD/LDAP, admittedly), the OUs all hang off DC.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for feedback about your setup. "**o**" is a [legal attribute](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/#attributes) from the [core.schema](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/core-schema.html#o).

Comment: Yes I know it's a legal attribute; that doesn't mean you can add OUs to it though. Looking at http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/ tail end of section 3.3 and beginning of 3.6 it shows you can have O,DC,DC (i.e. a human-readable name for the DC,DC hierarchy) and OU,DC,DC (a container within DC,DC hierarchy) but not OU,O,DC,DC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you certain that your LDAP directory contains the dn `o=home,dc=hoeft-online,dc=de`? The error suggests that it does not, but as you have not pasted the output of an appropriate `ldapsearch` command it's hard to tell.  Is suspect that is the issue, because otherwise I am unable to reproduce your problem.

I'm starting with OpenLDAP 2.4.47 on Debian Stretch.  I have a database for `dc=example,dc=com`; I start with:

```
$ ldapsearch ... -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -x -w admin -b dc=example,dc=com -LLL
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example
```

I can then add a new `o=home` using this LDIF:

```
dn: o=home,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organization
o: home
```

Which looks like:

```
$ ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -x -W -f add-org.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "o=home,dc=example,dc=com"
```

And then I can add an `ou=posix` like this:

```
dn: ou=posix,o=home,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: posix
```

Which looks like:

```
$ ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -x -W -f add-ou.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=posix,o=home,dc=example,dc=com"
```

And when I'm done:

```
$ ldapsearch ... -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -x -w admin -b dc=example,dc=com -LLL
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example

dn: o=home,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organization
o: home

dn: ou=posix,o=home,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: posix
```